# Oracle IS JSON in stored procedure

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

This simple query works fine:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SBM_MESSAGE_BODY IS JSON THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_JSON,  
       JSON_VALUE(SBM_MESSAGE_BODY, '$.CRMId') AS CRMId
  FROM SBM_SERVICEBUS_MESSAGE 
 WHERE SBM_ID=1;
```

Results are:

```
IS_JSON,CRMID
1,      CRM000001
```

Now, I put the same query in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_SB_TEST 
AS
    ls varchar2(4000);
    ls2 varchar2(4000);

BEGIN

    SELECT CASE WHEN SBM_MESSAGE_BODY IS JSON THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_JSON,  
           JSON_VALUE(SBM_MESSAGE_BODY, '$.CRMId') AS CRMId
      INTO ls,ls2
      FROM SBM_SERVICEBUS_MESSAGE 
     WHERE SBM_ID=1;

    dbms_output.put_line( 'IS JSON=' || ls );
    dbms_output.put_line( 'CRMId=' || ls2 );

END ;
```

And I got this compiling error on the line containing "IS JSON":

> [Error] Syntax check (8: 42): ERROR line 8, col 42, ending_line 8,
>   ending_col 45, Found 'JSON', Expecting: A  DANGLING  EMPTY  INFINITE 
>   NAN  NULL  OF   -or-   ANY  NOT  PRESENT

I am using TOAD

Comment: The procedure compiles fine for me in 12.2.0.1.0, which version are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Removing "hello" is normal behavior. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989

Comment: I don't have a 12.1.0.2.0 version and I checked in my local 12.2 version and it works fine. It's possible that the feature is available only in SQL until 12.1 but also works in PL/SQL for 12.2 and above. See [this](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ho4ewirsmcalcy7imxeqb5qfw)  for 18c.

Comment: It's weird cause the second line works JSON_VALUE(SBM_MESSAGE_BODY, '$.CRMId') AS CRMId

Comment: Oracle **introduced** JSON support in 12c R1 but **extended** it in 12c R2.

Answer (score 2):

JSON operators where integrated into PL/SQL in version 12.2 (see [Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2) New Features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-9B4D323C-079F-488A-A675-81B9730C4CE3):

> **JSON Improvements**
>
> - JSON operators are supported in PL/SQL.
> - Support for manipulating JSON documents using PL/SQL. This includes the ability to make incremental modifications to JSON documents.

So your Oracle version is sligthly too old to support it.

Before Oracle 11g it was typical that PL/SQL would only support a subset of SQL. Then Oracle improved it and brought it up to par. With 12.1, there was obviously a temporary set back.

Comment: Like I said above :
It's weird cause the second line works fine :
JSON_VALUE(SBM_MESSAGE_BODY, '$.CRMId') AS CRMId

Comment: `JSON_VALUE` is a function. `IS JSON` is an operator. So the Oracle announcement for release 12.2 is precise. The operators were missing, not the functions.

Answer (score 1):

If i m not wrong Oracle introduced JSONEXISTS with version 12c 12.2 so the procedure can be written like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SBM_SERVICEBUS_MESSAGE (
    SBM_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    SBM_MESSAGE_BODY CLOB
);

INSERT INTO SBM_SERVICEBUS_MESSAGE (SBM_ID, SBM_MESSAGE_BODY)
VALUES (1, '{"CRMId": 123, "CustomerName": "John Doe", "Amount": 1000}');

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_SB_TEST 
AS
    ls NUMBER;
    ls2 VARCHAR2(4000);
    ls3 VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN JSON_EXISTS(SBM_MESSAGE_BODY, '$') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_JSON,  
           JSON_VALUE(SBM_MESSAGE_BODY, '$.CRMId') AS CRMId,
            JSON_VALUE(SBM_MESSAGE_BODY, '$.Amount') AS Amount
    INTO ls, ls2, ls3
    FROM SBM_SERVICEBUS_MESSAGE 
    WHERE SBM_ID = 1;

    dbms_output.put_line('IS JSON=' || ls);
    dbms_output.put_line('CRMId=' || ls2);
    dbms_output.put_line('Amount =' || ls3);
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
    USP_SB_TEST;
END;
/
```

Hope it helps